# How to get name ancor tag to offset when linking to a different page?

Tags: html, css

I have some pages on a Wordpress site that have name anchor tags that initially get covered by the fixed/sticky header when clicked. I'm using some CSS that fixes that, but it only seems to work when linking inside the specific page(s).

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
a[name] {
  padding-top: 178px;
  margin-top: -178px;
  display: block;
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We now have `scroll-margin` to handle kind of thing.

From [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-margin/):

> **scroll-margin** is used to adjust an element's snap area (the box that defines where the element will be snapped to). Adding
>   scroll-margin is useful when you need to give an element space from
>   the edge of the container when snapped into place, but allowing for
>   situations where each element might need slightly different spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and info. I added the following code: 
html {
  scroll-padding-top: 350px;
} 
and it works, but works kind of wonky. And it doesn't seem to work without the initial a[name] code. Do you know if there's a way to implement this without having to add a class to specific div, etc?? Thanks again!